# Changing field types in a Hibernate entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, list, dictionary, h2

I'm using Hibernate to store a data model, which has a number of simple fields:

```
@Entity
public class Shape extends DomainObject {

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @CollectionOfElements()
    private List<Shape> children;

    @Column
    private int numSides;

    ... etc. ...
}
```

The `DomainObject` superclass keeps track of the `Long id`.

We'd like to make a change to the `children` `List`, so that instead of being a simple `List`, it's actually a `Map` where the key is the `Long id` (from the superclass).

```
@???
private Map<Long, Shape> children;
```

How are migrations/type changes of this nature handled in Hibernate? I'm not too familiar with this aspect of Hibernate - is there some method that can be overloaded to accept the `List<Shape>` (on the first load of the application, using the older data) and perform a manual generation of the new `Map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There shouldn't be any difference in the database: you just choose to use a Map rather than a List to store the Shapes, but the attributes of the Shape entity stay identical and thus the table storing the shapes also has the same columns.

Comment: Let's say I've been using the original data model for a while, and I have a Shape with 10 children. When I make the change to the data model and relaunch the application, what will the Map contain? What will the keys be?

Comment: When you use a Map, you have to use one of the attributes of the target entity (Shape) as the key of the map, using @MapKey. By default, the key is the ID of the target entity. So the map will contain all the elements of the list, indexed by their ID. If you need a schema change, use your preferred SQL tool to migrate the data, and then launch your application with the new mapping. But in this case, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Thanks - does Hibernate have any built-in mapping tools/functionality available? Something that can be performed inside our application? Our app uses Hibernate as a data store, and is in use on multiple client sites. It would be tedious to have to visit each location and perform a manual SQL migration. (For more complex migrations, that is.)

Comment: No, Hibernate doesn't have anything. But a simple SQL script wrapped in a batch file is pretty easy to use.